# Mapping complex datatypes to model classes (SOAP)

Tags: web-services, soap, groovy, soapui

I'm writing SOAP web service tests in Groovy/soapUI (the web service heavily takes advantage of complex datatypes). To make my life easier I'm looking for solutions to map complex datatypes to model classes in Groovy. Are there any automated solutions for this task, or do I need to write my own conversions?

I'm relatively new to SOAP and using the same classes for my data on the server-side and the client-side seems to be a good idea: please correct me if my approach is missing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to have an automated mapping between the SOAP Request/Response XML and your Groovy Model Object class? I don't think there is something existing. You need it to write it yourself. The only thing comes to my mind was the [dozer framework](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/). But this is actual for JavaBean Mapping, like POJO to DTO, maybe you should look at this anyway.

We also do Webservices with groovy endpoints, for the mapping we use groovy's `XMLSlurper` and the rest via hand.

I hope this helps.